# Insert an image into a BIRT report with a secured URL

Tags: eclipse, image, report, birt

I wanted to load an image in my report with an URL.
The following stackoverflow question answers that.
[How to insert an image into a BIRT report with an URL properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25264555/how-to-insert-an-image-into-a-birt-report-with-an-url-properly)

However, my URL is not public and requires authentication to access. Like, adding an Authorization token in the header.

How can I intercept the request to insert Authorization token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a new "Scripted Data Source" and write your request in JavaScript with the required authorization token to load the Image data into your Data Source.
Then you add a data Set to get the data from the scripted data source. Afterwards you add the Image as "Dynamic image" and load the data from the Data Set that gets the data from your scripted data source. This is a bit complicated, but it should be possible.

Please search for tutorials for creating a scripted data source by yourself. This is a complex field but opens up a lot of possibilities.